# how to skip line using for loop in java?

Tags: for-loop

So i want to skip a line after every multiples of 5, so from 1,2,3,4,5 //skip line, 6,7,8,9,10 //skip line. I cant do this with every i =5,10,15,20 being printed, instead its just a blank space. so how do i fix this?

```
package task;

public class Task {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i ;

    for(i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
        if(i % 5 != 0){
        System.out.println(i + " squared = " + i*i);
        }
        else
            System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code skips printing all multiples of 5, what you should do is check if the number is a multiple of 5, and if it is, skip a line:

```
for(int i= 0; i<= 20; i++){
    System.out.println(i + " squared = " + i*i);
    if(i%5 ==0)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: this is rly helpful

Comment: yes, i was able to complete my assignment. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

A bit of trial and error with the modulo operation should have yielded a solution, similar to the one below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  

    int skipEvery = 5;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        counter++;
        if (counter % (skipEvery + 1) == 0) {
            counter = 0;
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println(i + " squared = " + i * i);
        }
    }
}
```